# change radio button checked attribute on basis of label html using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a select drop down and if the onchange of select drop-down the option is yes than all the radio buttons should change to yes

```
<select class="is_poly_cover">
   <option>No</option>
   <option>Yes</option>
</select>



<input type="radio"  name="v1" class=" additional_option_type_7" checked="checked" value="251">
<label class="" for="251">YES</label>

<input type="radio" name="v1" class=" additional_option_type_7" value="254">
<label class="" for="254">NO</label>

<input type="radio"  name="v2" class=" additional_option_type_8" checked="checked" value="255">
<label class="" for="255">YES</label>

<input type="radio" name="v2" class=" additional_option_type_8"  value="256">
<label class="" for="256">NO</label>
```

Note: Everthing here is made dynamically and i dont have access to change the html so cannot add classes or id to the elements.

Here on change of is_poly_cover if its yes than all radio button goes to yes and if is_poly_cover no than all radio btns goes to No

attempt:

```
var set_classes = ['additional_option_type_8','additional_option_type_7'];

$('body').delegate('.is_poly_cover', 'change', function(e) {
    var is_poly_cover_text = $(".is_poly_cover").find("option:selected").text().toLowerCase();
    if(is_poly_cover_text == 'yes'){
        var label = '';
        var req_elem = '';
        for(var i=1;i<set_classes.length;i++) {
            req_elem = "."+set_classes[i];
            //console.log(req_elem)
            label = $(req_elem).next().html().toLowerCase();
            console.log(label)
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Please show your attempt .

Comment: okay..added.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through your labels and see if its value match with select if yes add radio `checked` above it to `true`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('body').delegate('.is_poly_cover', 'change', function(e) {
  var values = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
  console.log(values)
  //remove checked from radios
  $('[class*=additional_option_type_]').prop("checked", false)
  //loop through label (give some class to label then change label.thatclass_name)
  $("label").each(function() {
    //check value is same
    if ($(this).text() == values) {
      //add checked to radio
      $(this).prev().prop("checked", true)
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="is_poly_cover">
  <option>No</option>
  <option>Yes</option>
</select>



<input type="radio" name="v1" class="additional_option_type_7" value="251">
<label class="" for="251">YES</label>

<input type="radio" name="v1" class=" additional_option_type_7" value="254">
<label class="" for="254">NO</label>

<input type="radio" name="v2" class=" additional_option_type_8" value="255">
<label class="" for="255">YES</label>

<input type="radio" name="v2" class=" additional_option_type_8" value="256">
<label class="" for="256">NO</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  setRadioButton();
  $('.is_poly_cover').change(function()
  {
     setRadioButton();
  });
   
   
   function setRadioButton()
   {
       if($('.is_poly_cover :selected').text() == "Yes")
     {
         $('body input[type=radio]').each(function(){
              var value = $(this).attr('checkedvalue');
              if(value == 1)
              {
                  $(this).prop('checked',true);
              }
         });
     }
     else
     {
          $('body input[type=radio]').each(function(){
              var value = $(this).attr('checkedvalue');
              if(value == 0)
              {
                  $(this).prop('checked',true);
              }
         });
     }
   }
```

```html
<select class="is_poly_cover">
   <option>No</option>
   <option>Yes</option>
</select>



<input type="radio" name="v1" class=" additional_option_type_7" checkedvalue="1" checked="checked" value="251">
<label class="" for="251">YES</label>

<input type="radio" name="v1" class=" additional_option_type_7" checkedvalue="0" value="254">
<label class="" for="254">NO</label>

<input type="radio" name="v2" class=" additional_option_type_8" checkedvalue="1" checked="checked" value="255">
<label class="" for="255">YES</label>

<input type="radio" name="v2" class=" additional_option_type_8" checkedvalue="0" value="256">
<label class="" for="256">NO</label>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```